# How to use Feature Selection along with Leave One Out Cross Validation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, anova, cross-validation, feature-selection

I am working on a dataset related to a disease having 17,000 features and 120 samples. I am using leave one out cross validation in this task and I have incorporate feature selection in my experimentation. I used ANOVA FS technique. I want to execute this experiment in the following way:

1. In LOOCV, employ feature selection on training set in each fold. This gives us n (no. of samples) sets of selected features, each set
   contain top 10 feature
2. Out of the sets of selected features,
   select top 10 features based on number of occurrences in the sets
3. Again employ LOOCV with the top 10 features in order to compute
   accuracy

My question is, if I am doing this right or not? If no what are the issues in my experimentation?

Comment: In a training fold (first LOOCV), how do you select features? Do you employ another CV inside the fold?

Comment: In the first LOOCV, I am just employing feature selection selection. Basically, this cross validation is used to perform feature selection. I am not training models in this part.